# How do I use jq to combine two arrays from the same JSON object based on a unique key value?

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "a": [{
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Doe"
        }]
    }, {
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "Jane",
            "last": "Doe"
        }]
    }, {
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I would like to use jq to turn this into a single array of objects based on the value of "last".  The desired output would be something like this:

```
[{
  "last": "Doe"
},
{
  "last": "Smith"
}]
```

where only ***unique*** values of "last" that is a child of "b" are included.  In my case I don't care about any of the other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to the original question that uses `..` (i.e., that scans for objects with a "last" key, wherever they may be):

```
[.. | select(.last?).last]
| unique
| map({last: .})
```

This can easily be modified to solve the revised question:

```
[.. | select( (.b?|type) == "array")
 | .b[] | select(.last?).last ]
| unique
| map({last: .})
```

### Caveat

`unique` performs a sort.  If you want the order of .last values to be respected, then the following helper function can be used, provided all the .last values are strings:

```
def uniques(stream):
  foreach stream as $s ({};
    if .[$s] then .emit = false else .emit = true | (.item = $s) | (.[$s]=true) end;
    if .emit then .item else empty end );
```

```
| [ uniques(.. | select(.b?).b[] | select(.last?).last) | {last: .}]
```

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct for my question.  However, I simplified my example a bit too much when I asked the question.  The actual data looks more like this:
{
    "a": [{
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Doe"
        }]
    }, {
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "Jane",
            "last": "Doe"
        }]
    }, {
        "last": "other",
        "b": [{
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }]
    }]
}
I don't want the "last" that is a peer to "b".

Comment: I updated the sample in my original post to more accurately reflect the data.  I tried to rework your answer to solve it, but still not understanding this syntax I guess.  Thanks for helping.